# How i can retrieve value observable in reactiveform?

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular-reactive-forms

How i can  retrieve my url value in the reactive form ? I dont know how to extract value from Observable to be returned by function in which Observable is present. I need just a value from it to be returned, nothing else.

```
uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = Date.now().toString();
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref('/referentiels/' + filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload('/referentiels/' + filePath, file);
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
     task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
       this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
       this.downloadURL.subscribe((url) => {
            return url
        });
        }))
    .subscribe()
  }    
  onSaveReferentiel() {
    const nomSS = this.referentielForm.get('nomSS').value;
    const speSS = this.referentielForm.get('speSS').value;
    const webSS = this.referentielForm.get('webSS').value;
    const newReferentiel = new Referentiel (nomSS, speSS, webSS, ---url---);
    this.referentielsService.createNewReferentiel(newReferentiel);
    this.router.navigate(['/referentiels']); 
  }
```

Comment: what do you want to achive?

Comment: currently what error are you getting?

Comment: are you getting back any value try to console the subscribed data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176267/discussion-between-chellappan-and-newbiiiie).

Comment: I had reformulated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = Date.now().toString();
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref('/referentiels/' + filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload('/referentiels/' + filePath, file);
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
   task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
   this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
   this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => this.url = url
    );

    }))
.subscribe())
```

}

Comment: first try console.log(url) inside subscribe method

Comment: you are welcome brother. glad i am able to help you!